# In Laravel5.2, Passing perameter from Route to MyMiddleware, But getting Missing argument 3

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel5.2 and i followed https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware as per that i created MyMiddleware.php in Middleware folder
Here is code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class MyMiddleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string  $role
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role) {
        echo $role;exit;

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

In kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [            
            \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class
        ] 
    ];
  protected $routeMiddleware = [
             'absurd' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

In routes.php :

```
   Route::any('manager/dashboard', 'UserController@mndashboard')->middleware('absurd:Admin');
```

But I still get Error: ErrorException in MyMiddleware.php line 18: Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware::handle()

I tried everything but not working. 
Help Need Plz .!

Comment: remove the middleware from web group. Seems like it is where error is coming from

Comment: I need this middle ware for filter my routes,

Comment: ok.. then add the default parameter in your middleware. `$role = 'default_value'`

Comment: That will give me out put default_value, But i need it from Routes Suppose I careated.  Route::any('manager/dashboard', 'UserController@mndashboard')->middleware('absurd:Admin'); than it will give me Admin as output.

Comment: since you are adding the middleware to each route , I don't think you would need it in web group. Since, there isn't any way to pass value to web group middlewares, you can add the middleware to group individually. check the update

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: It doesn't work. I need each router separate permission so i m doing this. This example shown in laravel site but dont work in my site.

Comment: sorry but I am not getting it. You have added the middleware to web middleware group so that it can be applied with other middlewares. right ? Then you are also adding it to individual route . right ?

Comment: why do you you need it at both the places ?

Comment: First middleware for secure admin and second  middle ware is for check user role for particular  Role.

Comment: then you would better off defining two middlewares

Comment: ok i dont know how to chat here

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123051/discussion-between-jaysingkar-and-ankit

Answer (score -1):

Add default value to your `handle` method:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role='default_vale') {
        echo $role;exit;

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Update:

First remove the middleware from web group. Then add it to your route group as bellow

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'absurd:admin']], function(){
   //Your Routes
}
```